# How do I obtain a code point integer from a 1 to 4 byte UTF-8 encoded sequence in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8

I am Patrick Niedzielski, a programmer for the Free Software 3D adventure game [Humm and Strumm](http://hummstrumm.blogspot.com/).  I'm working on a minimal Unicode character class in C++.  I currently have an array of four bytes representing a UTF-8 sequence.

On GNU/Linux, I can just convert to UTF-32 with `iconv()`, but on Windows, I cannot do this.  Is it possible to convert the array to a single code point?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: What are you going to do with the code point after conversion? How much do you care about codepoints >U+FFFF ?

Comment: Take a look at http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: To clarify, if you're converting a single character then it implies that you just need to test it against something. Windows favours UTF-16 over UTF-32 for it's "wide" characters so UTF-32 tends not to have native interfaces, but that may not matter if you just need to test to see if the character is the same as something known to be <= U+FFFF.

Comment: @avakar: That looks like good stuff there. +1.

Comment: @Rob, only as part of GNUWin32 or Cygwin.  I would also like to keep my dependencies down.

Comment: @avakar, same as above, though seeing as it is open source.  I may do some copy-paste magic.  The license looks like a BSD license.

Comment: @Charles, I have a rather long table containing properties of the characters (from the GPL'd Qt library, and I'm only interested in character categories for scripting), and I need to know the code point of the value to access the character.  I do not believe I need to worry about code points that large.  Is it more difficult to use those?

Comment: @Patrick Niedzielski, what do you mean? It has no external dependencies and is a header-only library. What more can you possibly want?

Comment: @avakar, That's a good point.  As far as I can tell it's compatible with GPLv3 (Humm and Strumm's license).  I would like something more like this: http://www.deanlee.cn/programming/convert-unicode-to-utf8/ for its simplicity and compactness.  Of course, I want the opposite of the link I just provided.  I may have to just reverse the process.

Comment: @Patrick: Well, you can use a standard windows function to convert to UTF-16 and if it isn't the lead part of a surrogate pair, the first UTF-16 code point will be numerically identical to the UTF-32 code point that the original sequence corresponds to.

Comment: @Charles, I will probably do that.  If it were part of a surrogate pair, do I just need to worry about endianness?

EDIT: Nevermind, I found the part in the Unicode Standard.  You should add that as an answer.

Comment: Well, there actually are two UTF-16 encodings, Windows use the LE version.

Comment: @avakar, I think that is dependent on the system's endianness.  I don't know of a Windows computer that uses big endian.

Comment: The Win32 function that I was thinking of converts to a WCHAR sequence. So long as you don't try to interpret that as a sequence of bytes there are no endian issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently posted C/C++ code for decoding a UTF-8 sequence to UTF-32:

[How do I read UTF-8 characters via a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948308/how-do-i-read-utf-8-characters-via-a-pointer/2953960#2953960)

[Validate Unicode String and Escape if Unicode is Invalid (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969843/validate-unicode-string-and-escape-if-unicode-is-invalid-c-c/2977559#2977559)